# javascript list manipulation library/framework

Tags: list, javascript, javascript-framework

I'm looking for a javascript library/framework to manipulate lists. Is there anything like this already out there?

Ideally I'd like something equivalent to .NET's `List`. One of the main requirements is the ability to remove items from anywhere in a list. Some LINQ-like functionality would be great.

Comment: Is [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) something you're after?

Comment: Lists in the UI or just in code?

Comment: Thanks @pimvdb, underscore does seem to be something like I'm looking for, although it doesn't seem to have all I need.

Comment: @JarrettWidman, data structure manipulation, nothing to do with the UI.

Comment: See also: [jLinq](http://hugoware.net/projects/jlinq)

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: jLinq seems nice.

Comment: @Farinha: "doesn't seem to have all I need". Maybe tell us more about what you need exactly, and we can refine the answers. So far we only know you want to manipulate lists and to have a LINQ-like functionality. What scenarios do you have in mind?

Comment: Why does everybody need a framework to do the simplest things?  Learn the language and give splice() a try

Answer (score 3):

## [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)

It's not a substitute for a completely functional `List` replacement, but:

- it does get you a long way,
- it's well designed,
- well documented (and has a very nicely "[literate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming)-[programming](http://www.literateprogramming.com/knuthweb.pdf)"-style [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html)),
- easy to extend,
- lightweight.

It has a nice expressiveness and power to memory footprint ratio.

*(Note that is was inspired by the two following libraries, **[FunctionalJS](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/)** and **[Data.js](http://substance.io/michael/data-js)**.)*

## [FunctionalJS](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/)

It shares most of **[Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)**'s attributes, and is definitely more oriented towards functional programming. However:

- it is [less actively maintained](https://github.com/osteele/functional-javascript),
- it is slightly harder to use if you're not familiar with functional concepts.

## [Data.js](http://substance.io/michael/data-js)

More than a purely functional programming library like **[FunctionalJS](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/)**, **[Data.js](http://substance.io/michael/data-js)** also covers storage aspects, graph-like data-structures and other goodies.

*(It is funny to note that **[Data.js](http://substance.io/michael/data-js)** now lists **[Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)** has an influence in its newer iteration, while **[Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/)** already lists **[Data.js](http://substance.io/michael/data-js)** as its own influence.)*

## [List.js](http://listjs.com/)

**[List.js](http://listjs.com/)** is for manipulating HTML lists. It may not be what you want, but I thought of adding it here as well as it does its job very well and fits a nice niche in terms of briding data and UI management in one (not necessarily a good idea, but works for some cases).

## Others...

[Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/) (and many other JS libraries nowadays) supports some of the newer JS APIs or provides substitute implementations if they are missing, with some of them [fairly functional by nature](http://lazutkin.com/blog/2008/jan/12/functional-fun-javascript-dojo/) and design.

However, they don't push the concept quite as far, and these libraries are more heavyweight, so I wouldn't recommend them if that's all you want out of them.

[jLinq](http://hugoware.net/projects/jlinq), as mentioned by JanusTroelsen in your question's comments, looks very promising as well but I would be more concerned about the maturity of the library and its memory footprint for what it is (but the code seems very "spaced", so a compressed version might be acceptable).

Comment: there's also jSINQ, jsLinq and linq.js as noted by pomeh

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: yes, but as pomeh wrote it in an answer of his own, I don't want to deflect attention from his answer. If this one were to be accepted, then I could edit it and link to his here with credit as I usually do (I did it already in your case as it was a comment).

Answer (score 1):

May `linq.js` what you're looking for ? http://neue.cc/reference.htm

Also, http://microjs.com/ is a good site to find a library corresponding to a specific need :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try `manipula` package that implements all of C# LINQ methods and preserves its syntax:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/manipula